# how to plot with multiple component in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, pca

I want to plot all components and group points by clusterNum column. However, as I tried to learn so far, we can plot only in 2D and 3D ways. So, I would like to know normally how to plot or represent graphs with these all PCs?

```
This is what the sample looks like: 

            PC1         PC2         PC3        PC4        PC5 clusterNum
1    -2.3779857  0.85818117  0.77918535  0.1967346  0.9826036          2
2    -1.4290545  0.09556012 -0.06358622  1.3468587 -0.1525576          2
3     1.5621954  2.53686714 -2.57818785  0.0111326  0.2755555          1
4     1.9915498  0.19282116  1.34349507  0.0578331 -1.0146932          3
5    -0.4431131  1.38970833  2.34020611 -0.8359105  0.1402896          2
6    -1.9892596  0.37200044  2.00614197  0.5013188 -1.5358936          2
7    -2.6111509 -0.31112666  1.44419058  0.7313908  0.2597182          2
1977 -1.8662394  1.74827166 -2.37657231  0.4158580  1.1100287          4
1978  2.3477702 -2.24859797 -0.47305695  0.3690514 -1.1667859          3
1979  2.0797897 -0.14012792 -0.82941643 -1.2233560 -0.4523913          1
```

```
data <- structure(list(PC1 = c(-2.37798570730988, -1.42905447617503,1.56219540602943, 1.99154980323715, -0.443113128962729, -1.98925960995357,-2.6111508923784, -1.86623936673779, 2.3477701685881, 2.07978972115199), PC2 = c(0.858181174741465, 0.0955601160006672, 2.53686714046073,0.192821161122631, 1.38970832915268, 0.372000440681993, -0.31112665937417,1.74827166020088, -2.24859797467832, -0.140127921225955), PC3 = c(0.779185345162976,-0.0635862220559265, -2.57818784684844, 1.34349506727208, 2.34020610639405,2.00614196687586, 1.44419058101111, -2.37657231100357, -0.473056945068265,-0.829416434702976), PC4 = c(0.196734648339808, 1.34685865526758,0.0111326028445577, 0.0578331048357187, -0.83591054343165, 0.501318761327088,0.731390845165095, 0.415858033401411, 0.369051391354487, -1.22335597705293), PC5 = c(0.982603621624129, -0.152557597364265, 0.275555453841701,-1.01469324992585, 0.140289629133083, -1.53589363488684, 0.259718249982426,1.11002871887763, -1.16678589524657, -0.452391297542505), clusterNum = c(2L,2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L,4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1977L, 1978L, 1979L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a line plot with multiple lines, like this:

```r
data <- structure(list(PC1 = c(-2.37798570730988, -1.42905447617503,1.56219540602943, 1.99154980323715, -0.443113128962729, -1.98925960995357,-2.6111508923784, -1.86623936673779, 2.3477701685881, 2.07978972115199), PC2 = c(0.858181174741465, 0.0955601160006672, 2.53686714046073,0.192821161122631, 1.38970832915268, 0.372000440681993, -0.31112665937417,1.74827166020088, -2.24859797467832, -0.140127921225955), PC3 = c(0.779185345162976,-0.0635862220559265, -2.57818784684844, 1.34349506727208, 2.34020610639405,2.00614196687586, 1.44419058101111, -2.37657231100357, -0.473056945068265,-0.829416434702976), PC4 = c(0.196734648339808, 1.34685865526758,0.0111326028445577, 0.0578331048357187, -0.83591054343165, 0.501318761327088,0.731390845165095, 0.415858033401411, 0.369051391354487, -1.22335597705293), PC5 = c(0.982603621624129, -0.152557597364265, 0.275555453841701,-1.01469324992585, 0.140289629133083, -1.53589363488684, 0.259718249982426,1.11002871887763, -1.16678589524657, -0.452391297542505), clusterNum = c(2L,2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L,4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1977L, 1978L, 1979L), class = "data.frame") 

library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  select(-clusterNum) %>% 
  mutate(rowname = factor(rowname, levels = rowname)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-rowname) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(rowname, value, group = name, color = name)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

I don't think that is a common thing to do with PCA results though. Look [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggfortify/vignettes/plot_pca.html), [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.09-principal-component-analysis.html) and [here](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2019/11/04/interpret-graphs-principal-components.html) to learn what common practices for visualizing PCA results are.

Answer (score 1):

In additional the excellent resources mentioned by Till, I'd just like to leave a note here that in my field of study, people often use principal components to do neighbour embedding. This loses all numerical interpretation of axes, but it puts more similar rows closer than disparate rows.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(uwot)

data <- structure(list(PC1 = c(-2.37798570730988, -1.42905447617503,1.56219540602943, 1.99154980323715, -0.443113128962729, -1.98925960995357,-2.6111508923784, -1.86623936673779, 2.3477701685881, 2.07978972115199), PC2 = c(0.858181174741465, 0.0955601160006672, 2.53686714046073,0.192821161122631, 1.38970832915268, 0.372000440681993, -0.31112665937417,1.74827166020088, -2.24859797467832, -0.140127921225955), PC3 = c(0.779185345162976,-0.0635862220559265, -2.57818784684844, 1.34349506727208, 2.34020610639405,2.00614196687586, 1.44419058101111, -2.37657231100357, -0.473056945068265,-0.829416434702976), PC4 = c(0.196734648339808, 1.34685865526758,0.0111326028445577, 0.0578331048357187, -0.83591054343165, 0.501318761327088,0.731390845165095, 0.415858033401411, 0.369051391354487, -1.22335597705293), PC5 = c(0.982603621624129, -0.152557597364265, 0.275555453841701,-1.01469324992585, 0.140289629133083, -1.53589363488684, 0.259718249982426,1.11002871887763, -1.16678589524657, -0.452391297542505), clusterNum = c(2L,2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L,4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1977L, 1978L, 1979L), class = "data.frame") 

umap <- umap(data[,-ncol(data)], n_neighbors = 2) # Go up to 15 or so for larger data

umap <- cbind(as.data.frame(umap), clusterNum = data$clusterNum)

ggplot(umap, aes(V1, V2)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = factor(clusterNum)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>